# Change of Variables -Finding a Good Transformation

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have the region:

$2 \leq xy \leq 4$

$\space 0 \leq (x-y) \leq 3$

$\space x \geq 0$, $\space y \geq 0$

I'm wondering what would be a good transformation $(u = ?, v = ?)$ so that this region is mapped to a better region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$u=x,y$, $v=x-y$ seems to be a reasonable change of variables.

Comment: How would I make the equations in terms of $x = ?$, $y = ?$ considering that I need to eventually find the Jacobian?

Comment: Or can I find the Jacobian with $u=xy$, $v = x-y$?

Comment: You know how to solve equations, don't you?

Comment: that was a dumb question on my part, my bad